# NativeScript create fails with Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, npm, http-proxy, nativescript

This is for NativeScript version 0.9.1

I've been following the NativeScript setup for windows information [here](http://docs.nativescript.org/setup/ns-cli-setup/ns-setup-win.html). I'm now at a point where I'm trying to create a new NativeScript project using the following command

```
nativescript create NativeScriptTest --log trace
```

Except this is failing because it can't get the hello-world project template as indicated in the log trace

```
Starting watch on killswitch C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\xxx\KillSwitches\cli
AnalyticsInstallationID: xxx
monitor not started
monitor not started
monitor has started, connecting to http://xxx.monitor-eqatec.com/json.ashx
Statistics failed to be sent: 503
Statistics failed to be sent: 503
Creating a new NativeScript project with name NativeScriptTest and id org.nativescript.NativeScriptTest at location x:\xxx\NativeScriptTest
Using NativeScript hello world application
User-Agent: AppBuilderCLI/0.9.1 (Node.js 0.10.33; win32; x64)
httpRequest: { method: 'GET',
  host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
  port: null,
  path: '/tns-template-hello-world',
  headers:
   { Accept: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8, */*;q=0.8',
     'User-Agent': 'AppBuilderCLI/0.9.1 (Node.js 0.10.33; win32; x64)',
     'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate' } }
httpRequest: Sending:
[nothing]
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] stack: [Getter] }
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    at FiberFuture.Future.wait (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\fibers\future.js:488:15)
    ... more stacktrace
```

If I go directly to the URL `http://registry.npmjs.org/tns-template-hello-world` I get a JSON document back. The browser uses the proxy on my network, I suspect that NativeScript isn't for some reason. NPM is configured to use a proxy, `npm config list` contains this section

```
; userconfig C:\Users\xxx\.npmrc
https-proxy = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/"
proxy = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/"
```

So, should NativeScript be using this userconfig proxy information? Is there something I need to configure in NativeScript for proxy usage?

I have searched the nativescript.org documentation, but if there is any information there I can't find it amongst all the results for their javascript proxy object.

I have also tried setting the config via

```
npm config add proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx --global
npm config add https-proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx --global
```

which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a bug report for the issue on GitHub.

[Does not work behind proxy #302](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/302)

The next version has a fix included that allows a proxy to be set.